# Suppressing error messages from external functions

Tags: r

I am using the function `FixedPoint()` from the package `FixedPoint` for some computations in R. Even if a fixed point of some function cannot be found, `FixedPoint()` still returns output (indicating the error) and, *in addition*, returns an error message. I want to suppress any such additional error messages from being printed. Neither `try()`, nor `suppressWarnings()`, nor `suppressMessages()` seem to work. Please find an example below that produces such an additional error message.

```
library(FixedPoint)

ell=0.95
delta=0.1 
r=0.1
lambda=1
tH=1
tL=0.5
etaL=1
etaH=1


sys1=function(y){
  A=y[1]
  B=y[2]

  TA=(etaM*(1-exp(-(lambda*A+lambda*(A+B)+2*delta)*tL))-2*lambda*A^2-lambda*A*B)/2/delta
  TB=(etaM*exp(-(lambda*A+lambda*(A+B)+2*delta)*tL)*(1-exp(-(lambda*(A+B)+2*delta)*(tH-tL)))-lambda*B^2-lambda*A*B)/2/delta

  return(c(TA,TB))
}

FixedPoint(sys1,c(1.90,0.04))
```

Comment: And when you used `try` did you give it the argument `silent=TRUE` ?

Comment: Does not seem to work either. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I used `silent=TRUE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
cc <- capture.output(ff <- FixedPoint(sys1,c(1.90,0.04)),type="message")
```

where `ff` now holds the output you want.  (Alternately, you could wrap `capture.output(...)` in `invisible()` rather than assigning its return value to a variable.)

The problem seems to be that the error message emanates from an un-`silence`-d `try()` clause within the package code.